# Eclipse doesn't run my android applications

Tags: android, eclipse

I have installed eclipse and jdk several times and I still have the same problem. I'm working with vista x64 and I have tried with eclipse x86 and jdk x86 and with eclipse x64 and jdk x64 but the problem doesn't dissapear.

My problem is that if I run an application in eclipse the application doesn't run. It starts the android emulator but nothing more happens. Here's a sample log:

```
[2011-03-11 16:29:08 - HelloWorld] ------------------------------

[2011-03-11 16:29:08 - HelloWorld] Android Launch!

[2011-03-11 16:29:08 - HelloWorld] adb is running normally.

[2011-03-11 16:29:08 - HelloWorld] Performing com.hello.world activity launch

[2011-03-11 16:29:11 - HelloWorld] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device '2.1'
```

I have looking for help on the internet but I didn't find anything to solve this. Any idea?

Comment: How long are you waiting for the application? In my experience the emulator can take quite a while.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for if anyone has the same problem:

Problem solved. I changed my IDE. If I run from Netbeans there's no problem but the pluguin for netbeans isn't officially and it's causing me problems so what I do is start netbeans, create a simple project with Hello world and start the application.

Then I open Eclipse and I programme in eclipse and I don't know why but the emulator that netbeans started is visible for eclipse so now I'm able to work in Eclipse.

Thanks to every one for their help

Answer (score 1):

Have you made sure that you have selected the applicable project in the Debug Configuration?

Comment: You need to create a Debug Configuration that uses and applicable AVD.  When you do that, you need to make sure that you select a Project that you would like to run.  You also need to select "Launch Default Activity."

Answer (score 0):

Focus the main layout XML file.  Then select Run > Run As > Android application.